# Сгенерировать регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Описываю задачу полностью, чтобы был понятен контекст:
Получить через curl определенную страницу. Например это страница товара. Человек кликнул на цену. Определяем элемент. Если он содержит id, останавливаемся. Если не содержит, ищем ближайшего родителя с id. Потом ищем ближайшего родителя с class. Сам элемент нам уже известен.

Сам поиск элементов мне не интересен. Интересно возможно ли автоматом составить регулярное выражение, которое найдет и получит число, имея последовательность из родительского id, вложенного имени класса и вложенного элемента. Если возможно, подскажите как правильно это сделать.

Comment: Что за цифру должно найти рег.выражение на основании как минимум числа, но вероятно даже, что там у вас из id, класса и элемента даже не строка получается, а не понятно что?

Comment: Исправил цифру на число. Извините.

Answer (score 2):

Я понял как нужно поступить. Не нужно пытаться изобрести одно регулярное выражение. Нужен каскад регулярных выражений, которые приведут в итоге к нашему элементу. Сгенерировать такой каскад совсем не трудно. 
Еще проще будет задействовать [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
Максимум в 3 шага можно дойти до любого элемента.

Comment: Приятно видеть такие ответы. Честное слово.

Comment: Спасибо. Еще мне подсказали про вариант с xpath. Сейчас пока приостановился в этом направлении, но скоро продолжу.